# Let the screen turn but prevent screen lock

Tags: android, screen-lock

I would like to know if it is possible to let the screen turn off (as setted in device parameters) but to prevent the phone to lock while my application is running in front.

So, when something happen in the app, I can turn on the screen and the user dont have to unlock his phone. (It is a driving application, so it would be dangerous to make the user unlock the phone while driving)

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I dont want the screen to stay on : I want to be able to turn it on and when I do, that I dont have to unlock the screen.

Comment: `android:keepScreenOn=”true”`

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

I hope it will help. This will prevent your app to lock while your activity is visible.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this.. One of the way is to set this flag in your activities oncreate.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

For the other ways to keep your screen on.. [Link.](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-keep-screen-onawake-3-possible-ways/)